# How to center the editor window when editing markdown in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I have this in my settings

```
  "[markdown]": {
    //  "editor.fontFamily": "\"IA Writer Duo S\", monospace",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "editor.fontSize": 18,
    "editor.lineHeight": 23,
    "editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 80,
    "editor.lineNumbers": "off",
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false,
    "editor.centerLayout": true
  },
```

The last line `"editor.centerLayout": true` does not work. Is there a way to achieve the effect of centering the editor

I know there's an option to toggle centered layout but I'm wondering whether it can be achieved permanently when using markdown.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'm aware of it using the toggle under View > Appearance > Centered Layout.